# Creating automated python scripts that run every minute

Tags: python, time, automation, geojson

I have currently created a python script that runs when I double click and open it. It then creates/overwrites a geojson file. I would like to automate this script to run every minute. I have used:

```
import time

while True:
    # code goes here
    time.sleep(60)
```

This code works. However, it only works when I have the python file opened up by double clicking it. If I do not have it opened, the code does not run and the file will not be overwritten. Is there a piece of code I can write to tell python to run the code, even if the .py file is not open?

Comment: I would like run to the script when my laptop is on. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can run any code if the computer is off.

You need your script running on a server that is always on.

In any case, I would use a cronjob to start your script every minute.
The code you are using only starts sleep after the actual job, so the job does not repeat precisely every minute.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean, thank you for your help. I will research cronjob now.

Comment: As I am working on a Windows laptop, I unfortunately do not have cronjob and only task scheduler. I can not seem to get task scheduler working with the script I have for some reason, so is there a script I can write that tells the .py file I have, to repeat the same procedure every minute? I am not worried about if my laptop is turned on/off. Thanks

Comment: Try to follow this tutorial: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/analytics/scheduling-a-python-script-or-model-to-run-at-a-prescribed-time/