# How yolov5 auto detect when adding imgs to a folder?

Tags: python, yolo, yolov5

I already trained and got weight file in folder.
I would like to know how to automatically detect the photos in the folder instead of running the code manually, and every time I add a photo to the folder, it will detect the new photo and save the result.

Please tell me how to do it, thank you.

Below is my code to detect photos

```
import glob
import torch
import cv2
import numpy as np

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='yolov5/runs/train/exp8/weights/best.pt',force_reload=True)

# print(model)
for img in glob.glob("C:/Users/csie/PycharmProjects/Fridge/testdata/*png"):
    cv_img =cv2.imread(img)
    results = model(cv_img)
    results.save()
```

Comment: You can implement watchdog, which would keep watching directory for any change and on change run you script 

https://michaelcho.me/article/using-pythons-watchdog-to-monitor-changes-to-a-directory

Answer (score 0):

try writing a script that run the code in a while.
say.. after every 1 minute. or precisely, trigger the script to run the code whenever anything change in your input image folder.

try this: [How to automatically run python script, when file is added to folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557421/how-to-automatically-run-python-script-when-file-is-added-to-folder)

for reference:
[Creating automated python scripts that run every minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64696235/creating-automated-python-scripts-that-run-every-minute)

[Run python script every 5 minutes under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215153/run-python-script-every-5-minutes-under-windows)